# Setup.py attempts to import the package it is installing

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

**UPDATE**
This is a bug in the setup.py of the package

---

Attempting to install certain packages using pip and I get this error:

```
pip install saspy

command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
```

Upon reading the traceback I see that it failed while attempting to import saspy.This is an excerpt from the setup.py which is indeed attempting to import from saspy, while installing saspy. How is this supposed to work? I am using setuptools 36.0.1, pip 9.0.1 and (long story) python 2.7.8.

```
try:
  from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup

from saspy import __version__

with open('README.md') as f:
    readme = f.read()
```

Comment: Can you add the trackback?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a bug in a third-party library that should be reported to the maintainers of said library.

Comment: [It's already been reported.](https://github.com/sassoftware/saspy/issues/25)

Comment: Novice here. Should I delete this question since it has been shown to be a bug? I still want to give credit to the people who have commented and helped me solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a buggy setup.py.  It's a common mistake, since with a source installation, you can import the package from the unpacked source tree before it's been installed.

Answer (score 0):

saspy requires Python3. I would expect this issue is due to using Python2 to try to install it. Though I have never seen that error before when installing it.

Comment: Did you read the question you were answering? The author, at the top of the question, in bold type, indicates that the issue was due to a bug in the package. And in the comments, there's a link to the ticket. Please be more careful when responding to old questions that already have accepted answers.